# Next.js page renders twice when parameters in url

Tags: next.js

I have an issue regarding page rendering and url parameters within Next.js.

The code looks like this:

```
import { NextPage } from "next/types";

console.log("I log outside");

const FoobarPage: NextPage = () => {

  console.log("I log inside");

  return (
    <>
      Foobar
    </>
  );
};

export default FoobarPage;
```

When I open the page localhost:3000/foobar the console logs the following:

```
I log outside unsubscribe.tsx:3:8
I log inside unsubscribe.tsx:7:10
```

Now when I add parameters to the url localhost:3000/foobar?hello=world the log looks like this:

```
I log outside unsubscribe.tsx:3:8
I log inside unsubscribe.tsx:7:10
I log inside unsubscribe.tsx:7:10
```

This happens on production and on localhost (dev).

Instead of *Foobar* we're actually returning a component that's displaying a form. The form component accesses a *window* object which has been added via an external javascript file (script-tag in <head>).

Now the problem is: when there's a parameter in the url, the form gets rendered twice. It works fine if there aren't any parameters.

I simplified the code to the code example above without seeing any changes in the behaviour. I've also tried adding `reactStrictMode: false` to the next.config.js. That didn't help either.

It would be great if anyone could give me a hint or resource where I could learn how to handle my problem (..or get a better understanding of react/next.js rendering).

Comment: Does this help - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12010

Comment: You might be running in strict mode.